# WSDL Confusion -- what I'm seeing in my references isn't what I'm seeing in the wsdl file

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, wcf-proxy

I'm consuming [this wsdl file](https://www.strongauth.com/xml/SAKA2.wsdl), but I'm seeing different things in my c# reference file that that's created when I add a reference to it. For example, `EncyrptionClient` is nowhere to be found in the wsdl file, but it's present in the *Reference.cs* file. The same thing with `pingRequest`. I'm pretty unfamiliar with consuming web services this way, so maybe there's something fundamental I'm simply not aware of. My belief is that what is in the wsdl file would be created in the reference file, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

To consume the service, all I'm doing is right-clicking on the project and selecting Add Connected Service, then using the WCF provider.

Here are images of what I'm seeing in the Reference.cs file:
[image][image]

What about this process am I missing?

Comment: What are the "different things"? I don't think most of us are going to read an entire wsdl file.

Comment: _"It doesn't look right to me"_ - why not? What do you expect to see?

Comment: @Crowcoder you're right. I updated the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Updated the question. I would expect to see what is in the wsdl file created in the references.cs file, but that isn't the case. There are classes, such as EncryptionClient, that don't exist anywhere in the wsdl file.

Comment: The wsdl you link to is referencing other, external services with their own wsdl files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, EncyrptionClient is nowhere to be found in the wsdl file, but it's present in the Reference.cs file.

That's the client you'll use to communicate with the service.

> The same thing with pingRequest

The WCF proxy generator generates a request and response for each operation.

Comment: Ahhhhh, okay. `<xsd:element name="encrypt" type="tns:encrypt"></xsd:element>`

So, then the WCF Proxy is creating the `encryptAsync` method for me based on this? Thank you.

Comment: If that's a SOAP operation, then yes, it'll generate a method to call that operation, with the according input and output messages.

Comment: Hot damn. I figured it was something I just didn't understand about this process. Thank you!